# Transform multidimensional array into simple array?

Tags: php, arrays

I Have some variables in php, like this: $parsed[**X**][4] and $parsed[**X**][5]
the number of the **X** is going from 0 to 31 and maybe even more.
this many variables contains **only numbers**, and i want to check this  numbers and transform to variables like $ng* ex: $ng0 $ng1 $ng2 $ng3 $ng4 or $ng[0] or something similar... and then **echo** them where i want to.

```
<?php
$ng0="G";
if ($parsed[0][4] == "0") {
$ng0="NG";
}
if ($parsed[0][5] == "0") {
$ng0="NG";
}
$ng1="G";
if ($parsed[1][4] == "0") {
$ng1="NG";
}
if ($parsed[1][5] == "0") {
$ng1="NG";
}
$ng2="G";
if ($parsed[2][4] == "0") {
$ng2="NG";
}
if ($parsed[2][5] == "0") {
$ng2="NG";
}
$ng3="G";
if ($parsed[3][4] == "0") {
$ng3="NG";
}
if ($parsed[3][5] == "0") {
$ng3="NG";
}
?>
```

Well, you know that the code is not going like that up to 31! or even 130 in future or maybe more, so how can i make check automatically all $parsed[**X**][4] &  $parsed[**X**][4] and make one variable for each of them, thx.

Comment: I think that i have explain correctly, see the answer below its what i want to, you are welcome to edit my question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular `for` loop:

```
<?php
    $ng = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parsed); $i++) {
        if ($parsed[$i][4] == "0" || $parsed[$i][5] == "0") {
            $ng[$i] = "NG";
        } else {
            $ng[$i] = "G";
        }
    }
    print_r($ng);
?>
```

or if you **REALLY** want to use your variable idea (don't spam variables just because you can - use an array instead):

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parsed); $i++) {
        $variableName = "ng" . $i;
        if ($parsed[$i][4] == "0" || $parsed[$i][5] == "0") {
            $$variableName = "NG";
        } else {
            $$variableName = "G";
        }
    }

    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    foreach ($vars["GLOBALS"] as $variableName => $value) {
        if (preg_match("/^ng([0-9]+)$/", $variableName)) {
            echo $variableName . " is " . $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    /*
        ng0 is NG
        ng1 is G
        ....
        ng29 is NG
        ng30 is NG
    */
?>
```

Comment: Could also use a `foreach` loop:

    `$ng = array();
    foreach($parsed as $key => $value) {
        if($value[4] == "0" || $value[5] == "0") {
            $ng[$key] = "NG";
        } else {
            $ng[$key] = "G";
        }
    }`

Comment: the first one its ok, but thx.

Comment: @SweetieBelle You could shorten it even more if you really want: `foreach ($parsed as $k => $v) { $ng[$k] = ($v[4] == "0" || $v[5] == "0" ? "NG" : "G"); }`.